# Basic hello world program using uIP library on embedded board

Tags: c, linux, tcp, embedded

I am currently working with an embedded FOX G20 V board with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20 processor. I am hoping to be able to establish a connection by ethernet between this board, and a linux machine. The protocol of communication is using the uIP library (smaller implementation of TCP/IP intended for embedded boards).

Anyway, I've downloaded the [developpment kit](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AT91SAMSOFTWAREPACKAGE.aspx) offered by the processor, and it has countless examples of different types of communications, one of which includes a hello world program.

However, at this point, even with the example, I'm relitvely stuck. I am un sure which file of the hello world project it is I have to compile since there are many of them. Is it the `main.c` that is located in `at91sam9g20-ek.zip\at91sam9g20-ek\packages\basic-emac-uip-helloworld-project-at91sam9g20-ek-iar.zip\basic-emac-uip-helloworld-project-at91sam9g20-ek\at91sam9g20-ek\basic-emac-uip-helloworld-project\` or is it another file?

The whole point is to get a communication established by the board and the remote host (in this case my Linux machine), and send it "hello world" through ethernet. I am guessing that the application in this case defines its register addresses in which the board will be able to receive the connection from the remote host (I may be wrong).

In any case, I am hoping to get help by any "experts" that are familier with the project that may guide me, or explain to me how exactly to build this application they have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this board but according to [this link](http://elk.informatik.fh-augsburg.de/pub/rtlabor/ti-versuche/SAM7X/sam7x-oocd/atmel/at91sam7x-ek/softpack-1.5/basic-emac-uip-helloworld-project/basicmi_emacmi_uipmi_helloworldmi_project0_dir_description.html) the application is supposed to start a telnet server (on port 1000) and an http server. I suggest that you look at the output on the serial link (to get the IP of your board, let's assume 10.159.245.156 as in the example), and if you get what is expected then you can try to telnet to your board:

```
telnet 10.159.245.156 1000
```

The kit gives you project file for three toolchains (IAR 5.4, Keil and GNU). You'll have either to open the correct one depending on your toolchain (which one do you use?), or adapt if you use another one.

Edit: You apparently use the IAR toolchain, thus you need to open the *.eww file (for instance basic-emac-uip-helloworld-project.eww). This example only obtains an IP and displays statistics on the debug output (serial link?). There are other examples for a telnet or http server.

Moreover it's a detail but I think the emacs tag is irrelevant in your post. I think you confused EMAC (what is this?) and Emacs which is a popular text editor.